# Binding GWT widgets with models

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, gwt2

Can I bind GWT widgets with Java Beans (may be assumed models in client side) ?

For instance : using with Annotations as

> @Uifield @Bind(User.class) TextBox userName;

How can I achieve it ?

> *I assume If the widgets were bind with models , I can validate and render to view more fast , more clear codes and may be easy to modify.*

Comment: Are you asking it without using UIBinder?

Comment: @Braj No , UIBinder also may include or may be without it . But main point is I would like to bind widgets and models anyways.

Comment: at least you can bind the widget using UIBinder.

Comment: @Braj Yes , I can bind the widgets of UI in specific view controlled java classes but moreover I also want to bind with models for fast rendering or addition validations.

Comment: @Braj most of my RPC calls for server , I need to retrieve all input values and check validations before transfer. And then , from rendering server side datas to UI views , I need again retrieve , check datas before showing at UI views.

Comment: Ahh.... ! I got this feature in Vaadin.